# WPF C# Application updating the Entity Framework when installing an update

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

So after spending a few days scouring the internet with various search terms, I am coming up empty on what I should do, or how I should do a database update when an update is performed via an install application.

So far I have all the migrations working, and starting to look at getting the setup scripts to also do this migration. The question I have is, what is required to make this happen.

The App is nothing special and using the standard EntityFramework from NuGet package manager, there are no errors in the current Application and it works well, just I need to start looking at how to do this next stop. What are the best practices, pitfalls, etc?

I come from a web background, and spent 15 years doing these migrations on live production servers, so am not new to that process. But this process is totally alien to me, and I have no idea where to begin reading, experimenting.

Any help would be totally appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Code-First, and that there's only one database per installation then applying migrations at startup is probably the easiest thing.

EF Core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime

In EF6 use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migratedatabasetolatestversion-2?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: David, It's EF6 and I thought I made that clear. Anyway, I am aware of that page for MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, you shared, but I am not getting it to work as I have no idea what I am really doing. Have you got some examples I could pursue more about with that approach

Comment: And yes, it is Code First as the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following as it solved my issue, as the rest of the code was fine. The one thing that I could not find a definitive answer on, was how to update the database when the application was installed, and there was an existing database.

Turns out that the simplest way was to just call the following in the installation script, or when the application first started up.

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

The Configuration class is the Class generated by Entity Framework in case anyone is curious.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DBContext context)
    {
    //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
    //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method
    //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest to disable automatic migrations and instead create new migrations by hand when you change something - you can still apply them automatically.

Comment: However, I mostly work with EF6 connected to oracle. With oracle, automatic migrations are completely insane because often some manual intervention is needed for a db change. It might work better with MS SQL...

Comment: @grek40, please explain why you would recommend by hand? This is a WPF Application and I can't travel to all the corners of the world, to do this by hand. Unless I am not understanding what you mean!

Comment: I mean, `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false` and in your VS package manager console, with the model project selected, execute something like `Add-Migration "MyTestMigration"`. Then a migration file should be created in the same folder as your `Configuration.cs` with a name like `[timestamp]_MyTestMigration.cs` (and some resource+designer file). This migration will contain an `Up` and `Down` method, with the code to change your database. You can still use code to **apply** the created migration automatically when your application runs.

Comment: @grek40 and we are now back to my initial question, how to update the database when I release an update to my application.

As far as what is happening here at my end, the steps of creating the migrations and updating the database are done manually, the code I posted above is for my installer project for distribution of the migration scripts. Hope that clears it up a bit more.

Comment: I guess your `migrator.Update()` approach is fine (if it's working?). I just wanted to warn about the `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` part because it should not be needed for automated update.

Comment: @grek40 To be honest, I don't understand what that actually does, as in a manual scenario it doesn't auto-update any way. And if I have the code to run the configuration update, in the code and run it, then yes the database gets updated when I didn't want it to. So I guess for others reading this, that is sound advice to point out. Especially if you are in my position and still coming to grips with an ORM style framework in an Application world.